# What is the full name of "A New Beginning" in the Harvest Moon series?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

I have seen the "A New Beginning" game in the Harvest Moon series written three different ways:

- *Harvest Moon: A New Beginning* ([Harvest Moon Wiki](http://harvestmoon.wikia.com/wiki/Harvest_Moon:_A_New_Beginning) article title)
- *Harvest Moon 3D: A New Beginning* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvest_Moon_3D:_A_New_Beginning))
- *Harvest Moon 3DS: A New Beginning* ([Harvest Moon Wiki](http://harvestmoon.wikia.com/wiki/Harvest_Moon_3DS:_A_New_Beginning) page body)

What is the correct full name for this game? Was it released under different titles in different regions?

Comment: All the sourced links in the Wikipedia links mention 'Harvest Moon: A New Beginning'. The 3D(S) only mentions the platform that specific version was released on. I fail to see how the title of the game is unclear. Look at the pictures of the other links as well, quite clearly says it... Your third link even redirects to the first, where the name of the game is spelled out very large.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Regarding the wiki, I clarified that the confusion was over the article title containing one version, but the body text containing another. Since your answer that the correct form is "Harvest Moon: A New Beginning" and that contradicts the current answer, would you be willing to turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All covers I came across go by the Harvest Moon 3D: A New Beginning title.

But, if you are to refer back to the Japanese title (牧場物語 はじまりの大地), even though it doesn't literally mean Harvest Moon: A New Beginning, it still drops using 3D or 3DS. Which might explain why some sources went by Harvest Moon: A New Beginning only.

Comment: Could downvoters please explain how this answer can be improved?